# How to POST API URL with parameters to Instagram API

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I am trying to receive my `access_token` after authenticating a user on Instagram. I have already received my special code that you are supposed to POST and then receive the access_token.

In my iPhone App, how would I make an HTTP POST with the following parameters to the `access_token` endpoint?

Parameters:

1. `client_id`: your client id
2. `client_secret:` your client secret
3. `grant_type`: authorization_code is currently the only supported value
4. `redirect_uri`: the `redirect_uri` you used in the authorization request. Note: this has to be the same value as in the authorization request.
5. code: the exact code you received during the authorization step.

I am pretty sure that the endpoint url is "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"

Comment: Hello PhilSawyer, can you please share to me that how can i follow an user in Instagram through ios sdk ?